# Intermittent BSOD x139 KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE

Tags: windows, bsod

New Win 11 Pro domain-joined machine started throwing the BSOD 139 KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE soon after I started configuring it for regular use. It's a relatively high-end 64GB x7950-based machine with a 4070 video card that is used primarily for content creation, photo and video. There's a LOT of disk on the system. WhoCrashed doesn't point to any particular driver; ntkrnlmp.exe (nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69) throws the error. Crashes occur ever few days to sometimes 1-3 times in a day. At the moment, no crashes since 12/12. Windows memory test reports no problems. BIOS and drivers are updated.

A number of the disks on the machine are actually striped multi-drive collections of disks, a couple of MS Storage Spaces, one Asus raid array, and a couple of Windows striped drive sets built using disk manager.

There's nothing seemingly interesting in the Windows system event log. A couple of duplicate disk guid problems in a storage space, and an occasional  "Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort12, was issued." event on port 12, 13, and 14.

The system mfr (Digital Storm) suggests doing a bare-metal reinstall of Windows. Aside from taking a long time, it means going thru the whole configuration process again.

Any suggestions? TIA.